# Changing a Qsys design to run latest version of uClinux

Tags: linux, open-source, intel-fpga, uclinux, qsys

I'm using a [design](http://sdrv.ms/11cMAUy) in Qsys to run uClinux v2.6.

[image]

I would like to run a newer Linx but I wa told that I must change the Qsys design and add another timer because [newer Linux](https://github.com/altera-opensource) uses two timers. Is that correct and where can I find information about that?

The board I use is Altera DE2-115 and it works to run old linux 2.6 with the [Qsys design](http://sdrv.ms/11cMAUy).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the documentation here: https://rocketboards.org/foswiki/view/Documentation/NiosIILinuxUserManual

The information on the website confirms the two timers need, I have not tested with only one. I am using kernel 4.1 ltsi on DE2-115 and it works fine.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask which Qsys design you use? Did you make it yourself or is it publicly available somewhere?

Comment: I made it myself. Using Quartus 16.0 Lite. It is pretty simple CPU, Ethernet, Timers, JTAG UART and Sysid. BTW, I have not used the new generation of NIOS, I am using the old version of the processor.

Comment: That's wonderful. I wish I too could do it myself. Where can I learn how to do it? I suppose I must dig through the documentation a lot more.